# Sql query that not return null values in result

Tags: sql-server

I am really newbie with sqlserver.

I am querying some data from database and it is also returning null values with result.

My query is;

```
select amount, distributorid from paymants
```

Some distributors has `null values` *in* `amount column`.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: If you have no filte (WHERE clause) then rows won't be filtered..

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to fetch 'amount' values that are not null, or do you want to change all the null values into empty strings or anything else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `is null` (or `is not null`) to filter null values.

```
select amount, distributorid 
from paymants
where amount is not null
```

If you need all records with null amount with another value (say, -1) you could use `isnull` or `coalesce` as below.

```
select coalesce(amount,-1) amount, distributorid 
from paymants
```

Or, if you need only amount null records, you could do;

```
select amount, distributorid 
from paymants
where amount is null
```

Comment: @Rony: What does that mean? This shows three different scenarios OP could face when querying the database.

Comment: I am telling the same buddy.... U gave him 3 options. And all are very much useful. No other answer is require now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the rows that has NULL values, but that the value should be 0 instead you can write:

```
SELECT ISNULL(amount,0), distributorid FROM paymants
```

Link with info about ISNULL -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

and as pointed out in many other answers, if you don't want those rows to be returned at all, you can simply write:

```
select amount, distributorid 
from paymants
where amount is not null
```

Comment: Also, for DB2 AS400, ISNULL(amount,0) should be written as IFNULL(amount,0)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out columns with null values for amount using

```
SELECT amount, distributorid FROM paymants WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
```

However, if you're expecting amounts for all rows, then it may be a good idea to ask why those nulls are being inserted in the first place.

When you define the table, if there's a column in which you don't want to allow null values, you can specify the NOT NULL property

```
CREATE TABLE example ( someColumn INT NOT NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no filter (WHERE clause) then rows won't be filtered.

```
SELECT amount, distributorid 
FROM paymants
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT amount, distributorid FROM paymants WHERE amount IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION-1:

If you simply need to return values that are not null, then try the following:

```
select amount, distributorid 
from paymants
where amount is not null
```

SOLUTION-2:

If you not only need to return values that are not null, but also need to change the null values into empty strings or any other default value, then try the following:

Firstly, change all null values to empty strings or a default value, let's say, 0:

```
update paymants
set amount = ''
or amount = 0
where amount is null
```

Next, fetch the records:

```
select amount, distributorid
from paymants
```

Hope these solutions cleared your confusion.